# How to show the currently opened terminal sessions?

Tags: terminal

I am aware that I can open a terminal with `:term`. However, it may happen that I could `<c-w>q` and the terminal disappear. How to get it back in its current status? Or, more in general, how to see all the current active terminal sessions? I checked into `:buffers` but they are not there.

Comment: With `vim -Nu NONE -U NONE +'set hidden'`, `:terminal`, `C-w q`, `:ls`, I see the terminal buffer listed.